# R - Issue while knitting R Markdown -

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

I am getting the below error while knitting my rmd document to HTML.

> Line 71 Error in `[.data frame`(newdata, , object$method$center, drop = FALSE : undefined columns selected Calls:  ... predict -> predict.preProcess -> sweep -> [ -> [.data.frame Execution halted

This is the code I am using.

```
# Splitting training set into 75% training and 25% testing
set.seed(1)
inTrain <- createDataPartition(training$classe, p = 0.75, list = FALSE)

trainingset <- training[inTrain,]
testingset <- training[-inTrain,]
dim(trainingset); dim(testingset)

# Cleaning values with nearly zerio variance
NZV <- nearZeroVar(trainingset)
trainingset <- training[, -NZV]
testingset <- training[, -NZV]
dim(trainingset); dim(testingset)

# Cleaning NA values
navalues <- sapply(trainingset, function(x) mean(is.na(x))) > 0.95
trainingset <- trainingset[, navalues==FALSE]
testingset  <- testingset[, navalues==FALSE]
dim(trainingset); dim(testingset)

# Remove identification variables (first 5 variables of the dataset)
trainingset <- trainingset[, -(1:5)]
testingset  <- testingset[, -(1:5)]
dim(trainingset); dim(testingset)

# Remove predictors that are highly correlated
trainingset_cor <- cor(trainingset[, -54])
highcor <- findCorrelation(trainingset_cor, 0.90)
trainingset <- trainingset[, -highcor]
testingset <- trainingset[, -highcor]
dim(trainingset); dim(testingset)

# Preprocess values
xTrans <- preProcess(trainingset)
trainingset <- predict(xTrans, trainingset)
testingset <- predict(xTrans, testingset)
```

I am using the code on the dataset from the Coursera Project on Practical Machine Learning. I do not know if I am allowed to post the dataset in here. So please take a look at my code.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I cannot see the line 71 in the snippet of code you provided but from the error message it seems you are trying to use a column that is not existing in your dataframe. object$method$center - is it correct? Just try running this on a one line and see if it runs fine.

Comment: Hi Robin, thanks for the reply. Line 71 is where the code starts in my question. I have left out all code in before as there were no errors there.

Comment: You can provide an example of what the data set looks like in order to try to reproduce the error. Also, the lines `trainingset <- training[, -NZV]`, `testingset <- training[, -NZV]` and `testingset <- trainingset[, -highcor]` seem problematic to me. Shouldn't they be in order `trainingset <- trainingset[, -NZV]`, `testingset <- testingset[, -NZV]`, and `testingset <- testingset[, -highcor]`?

Comment: createDataPartition(training$classe... > classe??? Is it a typo? Should it be class/classes? But ya like Phil said you can think of an example that points out your problem and share it with a dummy dataframe/data